# POST requests to submit a form and get results

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to submit the number '02000001' to the form of this website and get the information using python: diemthi.hcm.edu.vn. My code is shown below but it doesn't work

```py
import requests

payload = {'name': 'SoBaoDanh', 'value': '02000001'}
r = requests.post("diemthi.hcm.edu.v/Home/Show", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

I inspected the webpage and it shows:
[image]

Comment: You are getting a `MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'diemthi.hcm.edu.v/Home/Show': No schema supplied.`. In simple english this means you should be using `http://diemthi.hcm.edu.vn/Home/Show` which indicates to `requests` that it should use `HTTP`. Even then, I don't belive that you will get your desired results. The response I get from the server is an error response (even though the status code is 200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1 - As mentioned in the comments, you should use the entire url with HTTP: http://diemthi.hcm.edu.vn/Home/Show

2 - There is no key called 'name' or 'value' in the payload sent to the website. The key is 'SoBaoDanh' and the value is the variable that you want to submit:

```
key = 'SoBaoDanh'
value = '02000001'
payload = {key:value}
```

Therefore, your code will look like that:

```
import requests

link = "http://diemthi.hcm.edu.vn/Home/Show"
payload = {'SoBaoDanh': '02000001'}
r = requests.post(link, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

And finally, it worked!

Comment: I did the same to you at first, but it still didn't work. You can try it. It looks so weird.

Answer (score 0):

add schema and add a trailing slash to the url